# Using R and an API to extract multiple stock market data

Tags: r, api, extract, lapply

I have setup an API access key with a data provider of stock market data. With this key i am able to extract stock market data based on ticker code (E.g. APPL: Apple, FB: Facebook etc).

I am able to extract stock data on an individual ticker basis using R but I want to write a piece of code that extracts data based on the multiple stock tickers and puts them all in one data frame (the structure is the same for all stocks).  I m not sure how to create a loop that updates the data frame each time stock data is extracted. I get an error called 'No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8' which does not tell me much. A point in the right direction would be helpful.

I have the following code:

```
if (!require("httr")) {
  install.packages("httr")
  library(httr)
}

if (!require("jsonlite")) {
  install.packages("jsonlite")
  library(jsonlite)
}

stocks <- c("FB","APPL") #Example stocks actual stocks removed

len <- length(stocks)

url <- "URL" #Actual url removed
access_key <- "MY ACCESS KEY" #Actual access key removed

extraction <- lapply(stocks[1:len],function(i){
  
  call1 <- paste(url,"?access_key=",access_key,"&","symbols","=",stocks[i],sep="")
  
  get_prices <- GET(call1)
  
  get_prices_text <- content(get_prices, "text")
  
  get_prices_json <- fromJSON(get_prices_text, flatten = TRUE)
  
  get_prices_df <- as.data.frame(get_prices_json)
  
  return(get_prices_df)
  
}
)

file <- do.call(rbind,extraction)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that this is not the most efficient way of doing this. A better way is to update the url to include multiple stocks rather then using a lapply function. I am therefore closing the question.